# pattern Recognizer in java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I'm writing a file renamer program in java. The issue is when giving input pattern.

When the input is complex like **(][)** in that case, I'm getting errors by **java.util.regex.Pattern** class..

The major issue of writing this code is that the input pattern and replacement pattern are user input. How can I handle such characters during processing ???

Comment: yes, thats part of unit testing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of how one can escape the special RegExp characters in the Java source code. I believe that you will have to escape the special characters manually if the pattern is being entered by a user.

```
package edu.mew.test.regexp;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExpPatternTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "filename()[].txt";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\(\\)\\[\\].*");
    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s1);
    System.out.println(m1.matches());
    String s2 = "filename.txt";
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(s2);
    System.out.println(m2.matches());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape special characters in a regular expression using [Pattern.quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: well, thats working fine. but while searching, its not recognizing the patterns from file name..

Answer (score 0):

They are reserved characters in regex
you need to escape them with two backslashes

//]

OOPS too much Microsoft influence I meant

backslashes \\]

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: A backslash is ` \ `, not ` / `.

Comment: You want `"\\\)"`, not `"\\\\\)"`.